# Java 8 Method references default method implementation

Tags: java

```
 interface HelloWorld {
    String hello(String s);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld h = String::new;
        System.out.println(h.hello("dasdasdadasd"));
}
```

When I execute the above method,it returns the value which I am passing in the  arguments **dasdasdadasd**
Which method of string class is executed or  is there any default implementation which java provides at runtime or by default it calls supplier.get() method?

Answer (score 5):

`h` was assigned a method reference to the `public String(String original)` constructor of the `String` class. That's the only constructor that matches the signature of the `String hello(String s)` method of your `HelloWorld` interface.

Therefore `h.hello("dasdasdadasd")` creates a new `String` instance whose value is equal to `"dasdasdadasd"` and returns that instance.

```
HelloWorld h = String::new;
```

is equivalent to:

```
HelloWorld h = s -> new String(s);
```

Comment: I am able to understand that. But why it is printing the argument which I passed..For example if I replace String::new with   s->s.toUpperCase(); then it calls to uppercase method of String class but in case of String::new which method it calls?

Comment: @PrasadReddy it calls `new String("dasdasdadasd")`, which returns a new String which contains the same characters as the original String.

Comment: So it is like create new object of string with the argument passed and return the same object right?

Comment: @PrasadReddy It creates a new String object and returns that new object, which means it does **not** return the same object you passed to it.

Comment: So this implementation is provided at run time?

Comment: @PrasadReddy What do you mean by "provided at runtime"? The `public String(String original)` constructor of the `String` class already exists at compile time.

Comment: return value for the function

Comment: @PrasadReddy The implicit return value of a constructor is the instance initialized by that constructor (a String in your example).

Comment: void hello(String s);void hello(); and how to write method references for this two methods?

Comment: @PrasadReddy that would depend on the logic you want executed when calling these methods. `String::new` would still work for both, since for the first, the implicit return value of the `public String(String original)` constructor can be ignored, and for the second, a different constructor will be used (`public String()`).

Comment: Can you provide me some dummy implmentation

Comment: @PrasadReddy what do you mean by dummy implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be rewritten as:

`hw` returns a string created from what it receives:

```
//Returns a string based on the input
HelloWorld hw = (s) -> {
    return new String(s);
};
```

Invoking `hello()` on that object returns "basically" the input:

```
//The value assigned to print is "dasdasdadasd", as returned by hw
String print = hw.hello("dasdasdadasd");
```

`println` Is receiving `dasdasdadasd`:

```
System.out.println(print); //"dasdasdadasd" is passed to println
```

Comment: This implmentation is provided at runtime?

Comment: @PrasadReddy The lambda expression here as well as `String::new` are implementations of `HelloWorld`. Java sees that the signature matches that `HelloWorld` is a functional interface and can create objects implementing it based on method references, lambda expressions, etc. Take a look at the javadocs of `java.lang.FunctionalInterface`, you'll see how it works.

Comment: what implementation does it provide when this called --HelloWorld h = String::new;
  h.hello(); --interface HelloWorld {
 void hello();
}

Comment: @PrasadReddy `String::new` is basically a `Function` implementation that takes and returns a string. Its signature is essentially the same as of your functional interface `HelloWorld`. Just as the lambda in this answer, it's basically like an anonymous class (technically different, though)...

Comment: if my method signature is void hello();
HelloWorld h = Customer::new;
  h.hello();
What implementation does it provide?

Comment: If your method is void, then `String::new` won't work, you would have to use a lambda expression or something else that conforms to a `void` function (consumer)

Comment: I am able to execute it.. It is not giving any error?

Comment: It will give an error at `System.out.println(h.hello("dasdasdadasd"))` because the function will be a consumer returning void, and you can't pass void to `println`

Comment: I am saying about direct call h.hello();

Comment: Yes, that will still work. Then the type of the implemented function is of the `Consumer` form (1 argument void method)

Comment: How did you  get to know this all things?Can you provide some references ?

Comment: @PrasadReddy If you read on functional programming in Java 8 and lambda expressions, you'll surely run into this content. Best place to look is the java.util.function package (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), there are also a lot of online articles, just google "functional programming in java", you'll find a ton of content...